# Show that $\text{sinc}(x)\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I have to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty} |\frac{\sin x}{x}|dx$ diverges.  A previous question proves that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ converges.  Maybe something can be done about the series $|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}|$ though I'm not sure what.

Comment: Which *previous question*? What have you attempted? Splitting the integration range as $[0,\pi]\cup[\pi,2\pi]\cup\ldots$ looks like a good idea, since the series $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+\pi}+\frac{1}{x+2\pi}+\ldots$ is (slowly) divergent for any $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$x\mapsto|\sin x|$ has period $\pi$. So
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{|\sin x|}x\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}x\,dx
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x+(n-1)\pi}\,dx
\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{n\pi}\,dx
$$etc.

Comment: What makes it clear that the last expression diverges?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})|}{\frac{n\pi}{2}}$ diverges and obviously $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx>\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})|}{\frac{n\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, edited the proof. check it now.

Comment: The *obviously* part still has something unclear. I would be more satisfied by an explicit estimation like $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}|\text{sinc}(x)|\,dx \geq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\pi}{3n}$$ given by inscribing rectangles in the region enclosed by the $x$-axis and the graph of $|\text{sinc}(x)|$. As stated, your inequality is clearly correct since both sides are divergent, but there is no explanation for taking such particular divergent series as a lower bound.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})|}{\frac{n\pi}{2}}$ is a Reimann sum for the integral taking the partition of $[0,\infty)$ as $[0,\pi),[\pi,2\pi),\cdots,[n\pi,(n+1)\pi),\cdots$

Comment: Such intervals do not have unit length. Your inequality is off by a $\pi/2$ factor. Why such Riemann sum provide an actual *lower* bound?

Comment: True that, edited likewise

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{M}|\text{sinc}(x)|\,dx =\frac{2}{\pi}\log(M)+O(1)$$ by integration by parts.